# How to send email which add a calendar event (not invite)?

Tags: calendar, icalendar, rfc5545

I know how to send a calendar invite by php (icalendar) but I want to just add an event to the receiver's calendar by sending an email. So that there is no RSVP buttons (Outlook) or other response needed.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi @MarianneSjöberg

looks like there is a challange with google and outlook calendar when we use RSVP:FALSE. Are there any alternate solution? stackoverflow.com/a/62444892/1877909

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between a calendar event and an invite: they both use the [icalendar](/questions/tagged/icalendar) standard.
The appearance of the RSVP buttons depends on the iCalendar `RSVP` parameter in the  `ATTENDEE` lines.

For example:

```
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=FALSE;CN=Jennifer:mailto:jen@test.ex
```

The important parameter in there is `RSVP`. It indicates whether the organizer would like to receive an RSVP or not. Its default value is false, so omitting the parameter establishes the same effect: the recipient receives the invite, and does not request a RSVP.

Note: mail software manufacturers may choose to ignore this: nothing can be done about that... :)

More info about RSVPs: http://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-2-17-rsvp-expectation.html

Comment: Surprising how difficult it has been to find this information!

Comment: looks like there is a challange with google and outlook calendar when we use RSVP:FALSE. Are there any alternate solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62444892/1877909

@DdW