# How to disable rsvp response from a created .ics file

Tags: outlook, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, google-calendar-reminders

I'm working with ICS files sending by email to our customers. I'd like to disable the RSVP response to attendees (our customers). Does someone know how to disable it?

Comment: I am looking for the same solution, did you find any alternative to RSVP: FALSE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-2-17-rsvp-expectation.html, use

```
RSVP=FALSE
```

or omit the RSVP.  The specification says the default is false.

Comment: Even after set RSVP=FALSE the Google Calendar and Microsoft Outlook Calendar does not obey it, the RSVP buttons continue being displayed, and the ICS email reply with the attendee's RSVP continue being sent by them. Does someone know the reason despite the "3.2.17. RSVP Expectation"?

Comment: I see that this may be a thing with google calendar.  I realise you probably programmatically sending however - since there are posts saying it's not possible to turn off RSVP when sending from google calendar it may mean google just always does the RSVP thing as apart of their 'are you attending' ?  Posts imply outlook does have concept. and suggesting one creates an gmail filter to filter them out in google.  https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/1059097?hl=en and  https://xfanatical.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-the-rsvp-responses-from-google-calendar/

Comment: Thank you anmari, let's wait Google and Microsoft answers about this "bug" here too. It's odd there is an option to disable in RFC and they don't follow the rule.

Comment: @anmari - I am looking for the same solution, did you find any alternative to RSVP: FALSE?